# Angular 2 - rc.2 packages not installing correctly

Tags: angular

I am trying to update to Angular 2 rc 2 using the command `npm install --save @angular/core @angular/compiler @angular/common @angular/platform-browser @angular/platform-browser-dynamic rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 zone.js@0.6.12`, but it not installing correctly it seems. In **node_modules/@angular/core**, **core.umd.js** is not found. In **node_modules/@angular/common**, **common.umd.js** is not found. the same thing for others too. Can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct path is:

```
~/node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.min.js

// for other packages too
~/node_modules/@angular/PACKAGE/bundles/PACKAGE.umd(.min).js
```

Update your SystemJS configuration to match this structure...

Comment: perfect. it works now. when did they change? and i have a question on how to update using npm cmd to angular 2 rc.3 when it releases. can i do with the same command `npm install --save @angular/core @angular/compiler @angular/common @angular/platform-browser @angular/platform-browser-dynamic rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 zone.js@0.6.12`?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not an expert on npm (: at worst you have to manually delete things from `package.json` then run command and it will update...

Comment: even i'm not an expert on npm too. ok i will check with that after it releases